# GPS location angular-leaflet -directive

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

Re: Angular-leaflet-directive used with Ionic.  I wondered if anyone knows how to return the current GPS location to a map - equivalent to map.locate in leaflet?  Any advice greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `map.locate()` like this:

```
function MapCtrl($scope, leafletData) { 
    $scope.getLocation = function() {
        leafletData.getMap('map').then(function(map) {
            map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16, watch: true, enableHighAccuracy: true});
            map.on('locationfound', function (e) {
                console.log(e.latlng, e.accuracy)
            });
    };
}
```